# Do you use more mobile data with Wi-Fi off than with Wi-Fi on (connected to Wi-Fi or not)

Tags: cellular-data

Does using your mobile data while having Wi-Fi off when not connected burn data faster than using mobile data while having Wi-Fi on when not connected to Wi-Fi?

Answer (score 1):

You can measure this yourself by going to settings app and using the reset option to then track data and watch how much you use over a set period and then again repeating the steps with Wi-Fi in the other state.

In general, you should leave Wi-Fi on so that it connects when it can if you are concerned with mobile data usage.

I can't see a situation where an app developer would notice that Wi-Fi was off and then send more data over mobile/cellular data, but it's something that a developer could in fact do.

You'd have to measure things to be 100% sure. My guess is even if there is a difference, it would be so small as to not matter, though.

Comment: You can also point out that Wi-Fi on helps Apple's Location Service to give better positioning information. Even if you are not connected to the wireless LAN, it uses the information to get more precise triangulation. Otherwise it is relying solely on triangulation with Cellular towers and GPS signals.

Comment: Yes  @AMR - WiFi on has many benefits. AirDrop, AirPlay peer to peer, better trilateralation for location services. My guess is Apple realizes some people turn off WiFi for decent reasons so adding cellular boost allows all these other features to work when people leave bluetooth/WiFi on all the time.

Comment: When I remember I use Airplane Mode when I enter the Underground, though I do have to say that iPhone does a much better job of preserving battery life in the absence of a signal than Android did.